# How does a view with union handle where's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, union

Let's say I have a View like this

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS

SELECT Id, Name FROM Source1
UNION
SELECT Id, Name FROM Source2
```

Then I query the View

```
SELECT Id, Name From MyView WHERE Name = 'Sally'
```

Will SQL Server internally first Select from Source1 and Source2 all the Data and then apply the where or will it put the where for each Select statement?

Comment: Toggle `show actual execution plan` button on, then run your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server *can* move predicates around as it sees fit in order to optimize a query. Views are effectively macros that are expanded into the body of the query before optimization occurs.

What it will do in any particular case isn't 100% possible to predict - because in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

For a trivial example like this, I would *expect* it to evaluate the predicate against the base tables and then perform the union, but only an examination of the query plan on *your* database, with *your* tables and indexes could answer the question for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the optimizer, cardinalities, indices available etc but yes it will apply the criteria to base tables where appropriate.

Note that your UNION as oppose to a UNION ALL requires a SORT to remove duplicates.